# Creating TeamCIty project by importing Kotlin DSL

Tags: kotlin, teamcity, dsl

I am trying to create TeamCity project/build configuration using REST API. I am curious if it's possible by importing Kotlin DSL script?

My goal is to create project/build configurations dynamically by existed Kotlin DSL scripts and TeamCity REST API. How can I achieve it? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Action "Create project from URL" analyzes repository and if it founds .teamcity there it will offer to import project from there.

You can try to import this project as an example: https://github.com/JetBrains/teamcity-test-metadata-demo

Comment: I know about "Create project from URL" feature, but I need to create TeamCity project from REST client passing existed Kotlin DSL script. Is it possible?

This is my workflow:

1. I have different Kotlin DSL scripts
2. Depends on conditions I create TeamCity projects from chosen Kotlin DSL script
3. I run auto generated projects by TeamCity REST API

Comment: At the moment REST API does not support it. As a workaround you can take a look what HTTP requests are sent by create from URL page and emulate them in your scripts.

Comment: Pavel Sher, thanks for the advice. I will try... I also think about teamcity plugin which will have endpoint to receive a kotlin dsl to create a project - is it possible to do now with Open API?